# Getting each element from a site

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using `JSoup 1.7.3` to get some data from a webpage. I am selecting the location Elements fo my page like that.

```
Elements location = doc.select("div[class=Location]");
location.text().toString();
```

I am getting back:

`LA NYC Washington Springfield etc.`

However, I would like to get back element by element so that I can write each into the domain object location. Any recommendation how to implement that?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Elements](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) object implements `List<Element>` and therefore has an `Iterator<Element>`. You can think of the `Elements` object that jsoup provides as effectively the equivalent to a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) containing [Element](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html) objects. You can get each element with a simple `for` loop:

```
for (Element element : location) {
    System.out.println(element.toString());
}
```

This `for` loop automatically uses the `Iterator` to loop over each `Element` object returned from your `select` query against the document object.

Comment: Can you please add more explanation so we can learn as well ?thank you.

Comment: @KickButtowski Which part is unclear? I'd be happy to expand on anything that's confusing.

Comment: wowww you look young. Just what is elements. I am looking for motivation to learn JSoup :) Is it possible to use lambda for loop for this matter?

Comment: I've added some additional information, but essentially `Elements` is a `List` of `Element` objects. It's a custom object provided by jsoup to be able to loop over DOM elements.

Comment: thank you it made it more clear specaillay this sentence "It's a custom object provided by jsoup to be able to loop over DOM elements.".

Comment: can we used forEach for traversing the list? +1 for being helpful :)

Comment: I'm not sure what forEach you mean. In Java, the code I provided above is essentially a forEach. Since `Elements` can be treated exactly like a Java `List`, you can use any method for looping over its contents that you would normally with a list. So something like `for (int i = 0; i < location.size(); i++) { System.out.println(location.get(i).toString()); }` would also work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61195/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-marc-baumbach).